# How to query show all pdbs in Oracle 12c with user normal

Tags: oracle, containers, oracle12c

When i use query bellow to display pluggable in Oracle 12c with user "sys as sysdba"

> select name from v$containers;

I displayed all pluggable. But when i connect with user normal. I display CDB$ROOT only.
I want to use user normal to display all pluggable. what do I need grant permission for user normal to display all pluggable same as "sys as dba"?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

Only users in the container database will be able to see pluggable databases; so you would need to create a user ID in the container database, and grant that user the role `SELECT_CATALOG_ROLE` and `CREATE SESSION` and then log into the container database with that new user ID, and you should be good.

By design and intent, users created in a pluggable database cannot see other pluggable database contents.  That's one of the main benefits; isolation.

Comment: Thanks for your help. But can you guide create a User in the container database?I try with query bellow but it isn't successfull
$sys /as sysdba
SQL>ALTER SESSION SET container = cdb$root;
SQL>alter session set "_ORACLE_SCRIPT"=true;
SQL>create user zabbix identified by "zabbix" CONTAINER=ALL;
SQL>GRANT SELECT_CATALOG_ROLE TO ZABBIX;
SQL>GRANT CREATE SESSION TO ZABBIX;

Comment: In CDB database the common username should have a prefix C## i,e C##Zabbix